# Computing the limit using equivalent functions: is that correct?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

Unlike many how-to questions, I would like to know whether my solution is correct and whether all my transformation are equivalent.

Here's the limit I need to compute: $$\underset{x\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\frac{\sqrt[5]{x^{3}+1}-\sqrt[5]{3x^{4}+2}}{\sqrt[3]{7x^{2}-3x+2}}$$

**Step 1**

I say $$\sqrt[5]{x^{3}+1}-\sqrt[5]{3x^{4}+2}\sim-\sqrt[5]{3x^{4}+2}, x\rightarrow\infty$$
because $$\underset{x\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\frac{\sqrt[5]{x^{3}+1}-\sqrt[5]{3x^{4}+2}}{-\sqrt[5]{3x^{4}+2}}=\underset{x\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\left(-\sqrt[5]{\frac{x^{3}+1}{3x^{4}+2}}+1\right)=0+1=1$$

Thus,

**Step 2**: $$\underset{x\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\frac{\sqrt[5]{x^{3}+1}-\sqrt[5]{3x^{4}+2}}{\sqrt[3]{7x^{2}-3x+2}}=\underset{x\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\frac{-\sqrt[5]{3x^{4}+2}}{\sqrt[3]{7x^{2}-3x+2}}$$

**Step 3**: $$\underset{x\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\frac{-\sqrt[5]{3x^{4}+2}}{\sqrt[3]{7x^{2}-3x+2}}=\underset{x\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\frac{-\sqrt[5]{x^{4}\left(3+2/x^{4}\right)}}{\sqrt[3]{x^{2}\left(7-3/x+2/x^{2}\right)}}=$$

$$=\underset{x\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}-\frac{x^{\frac{4}{5}}\sqrt[5]{\left(3+2/x^{4}\right)}}{x^{\frac{2}{3}}\sqrt[3]{\left(7-3/x+2/x^{2}\right)}}=-\underset{x\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}x^{\frac{2}{15}}*\underset{x\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\frac{\sqrt[5]{3}}{\sqrt[3]{7}}=-\infty$$

**Answer**: $-\infty$

Are all the transformation correct and equivalent?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: What you've done is ok. you handwave a bit at points but the ideas are pretty good.

Comment: @DonThousand Thank you, "you handwave" - what do you mean by that? You mean, I gave a lot of detail of how I did things?

Comment: @alekscooper hand wave means the exact opposite of that

Comment: @alekscooper The handwave part is the function $\sim$ function as $x\to\infty$ arguments. Technically, that is not allowed, but you have the correct idea.

Comment: @DonThousand Oh, I see. >>Technically, that is not allowed, but you have the correct idea. 

Could you please explain why it is not allowed and yet the idea is correct. I just read a book (in Russian, so I won't name it here) that says that we can replace functions with equivalent ones. I may have misunderstood somethings, that's why I posted my questions on MSE here.